# Select among different color shades before document beginning

Tags: color, conditionals, expl3, cases

I am creating a CV under Latex (based on the altacv template but it does not have such importance) and in  the preamble of my .tex document, I am trying to find a solution to be able to quickly test a configuration of color shades.

Since I discovered the LaTeX3 interface and its functions, I tried to used the `\str_case:nn` function to realize a kind of switch case.

But I am not getting the desired result and after compilation, the default colors from the class are used and not the new ones I wished from my configuration in the .tex document.

I fear that it is because I'm trying to use it in the preamble without really "calling it" and not after my `\begin{document}`, am I right ? But I don't really see how to realize such call.

Here, is my code.
As you can see, I made some variables in order to test if a case was really considered during compilation.
Also, I am not sure if the commands used for my grey hue color selection are correct. I am using the xcolor package.

```
% Available options
    \str_const:Nn \l_greyColorHue_str {greyHue}
    \str_const:Nn \l_blueColorHue_str {blueHue}
    
    % To modify to choose the switch-case option
    \str_set_eq:NN \l_colorHueSelection_str \l_greyColorHue_str
    
    % String to verify if the switch case worked
    \str_new:N \l_effectiveColorHue_str
    
    %% Color fields definition
    \str_case:nn {\l_colorHueSelection_str}
    {
        {\l_greyColorHue_str} {
            \colorlet{name}{\color[Gray]{15}} % Used for : \name
            \colorlet{tagline}{\color[Gray]{13}} % Used for : \tagline
            \colorlet{heading}{\color[Gray]{13}} % Used for : \cvsection
            \colorlet{headingrule}{\color[Gray]{15}} % Used for : \rule
            \colorlet{subheading}{\color[Gray]{13}} % Used for : \cvsubsection, \cvsubsubsection
            \colorlet{accent}{\color[Gray]{10}} % Used for : \cvref(#1), \cvskill(#1), \skillfive, \cvachievment(#1), \cvevent(#1), \quote, \printinfo(#1)
            \colorlet{emphasis}{\color[Gray]{9}} % Used for : \cvref(#1), \cvskill(#1) \cvachievment(#2), \cvevent(#1)
            \colorlet{body}{\color[Gray]{15}} % Used for : all text color
            
            \str_set_eq:NN \l_effectiveColorHue_str \l_greyColorHue_str
        }
    
        {\l_blueColorHue_str} {
            \colorlet{name}{black} % Used for : \name
            \colorlet{tagline}{RoyalBlue} % Used for : \tagline
            \colorlet{heading}{RoyalBlue} % Used for : \cvsection
            \colorlet{headingrule}{black} % Used for : \rule
            \colorlet{subheading}{Navy} % Used for : \cvsubsection, \cvsubsubsection
            \colorlet{accent}{MediumBlue} % Used for : \cvref(#2), \cvskill(#2), \skillfive, \cvachievment(#1), \cvevent(#2), \quote, \printinfo(#1)
            \colorlet{emphasis}{MidnightBlue} % Used for : \cvref(#1), \cvskill(#1) \cvachievment(#2), \cvevent(#1)
            \colorlet{body}{black} % Used for : all text color

            \str_set_eq:NN \l_effectiveColorHue_str \l_blueColorHue_str
        }
    }
```

Then, I begin my document and return my variable `\l_effectiveColorHue_str` to see its content in the generated document.

```
\begin{document}

[...]

\makecvheader

\ExplSyntaxOn
    Selected~coloration~: \\
    (~ \str_use:N \l_effectiveColorHue_str ~)
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Do you have any idea to make this work or even another solution with "classic" Latex code in order that I can easily switch between different shades of colors for test without overwritting my commands or commenting/Uncommenting my `colorlet` selections ?

Comment: Try `\str_case_e:nn` instead.  As it is, it compares the string `\l_colorHueSelection_str` with `\l_greyColorHue_str`, rather than the _value_ of these variables

Comment: Oh godness, it works ! 
I am so ashamed I didn't read just a little further in the interface3 documentation to see it...
Thank you so much !

Comment: No reason to be ashamed at all!  We're all here to learn. (also `interface3` is _huge_ :)  I will write an answer with a bit more detail for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions in the `str` module take their arguments as strings always, so

```latex
\str_case:nn { \l_colorHueSelection_str }
  {
    { \l_greyColorHue_str } { ... }
    { \l_blueColorHue_str } { ... }
  }
```

compares the *strings* `\ l _ c o l o r H u e S e l e c t i o n _ s t r` (24 characters) and `\ l _ g r e y C o l o r H u e _ s t r` (19 characters) rather than the *contents* of the `str` variables `\l_colorHueSelection_str` and `\l_greyColorHue_str`.  The strings are obviously different, but their contents might not be, which is what you want to compare.

To compare the contents, you can use `\str_case_e:nn`.  The `e` stands for `expanded`, which means it will first *expand* the strings being compared, and then compare them.

---

A few nitpicks on your coding style:

- You do `\str_const:Nn \l_greyColorHue_str {greyHue}`, but the name `\l_greyColorHue_str` indicates a `l`ocal variable.  Constants should be named `\c_...`.
- More generally, variables in `expl3` should be named `\<scope>_<module>_<name>_<type>`, where:

  - `<scope>` is either `l`ocal, `g`lobal or `c`onstant;
  - `<module>` is like a name space (for example the name of your package);
  - `<name>` describes the variable.  This part may contain one or more `_` for clarity;
  - `<type>` is the type of variable, for example `tl` or `str` or `int`...

  so your variable names would be better as `\c_impish_grey_color_hue_str` and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the tips & tricks !